# access denied for image file server in nginix

Tags: nginx, prestashop, plesk

I am using prestashop on nginx provided by plesk . two image on inner folders  have the same permission but one of them is available from browse the other is not !!

I've already gave them both 777 permission and their parent folder have the same permission either.

How I can  access them from Browser?

Edit: 
the physical address of Images Are like that : `/var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/modules/slider/img/view/slides/1.jpg`

and the URI that i'm using is `site.com/modules/slider/img/view/slides/1.jpg`
and the error_log is `Permission denied: access to /modules/slider/views/img/slides/1.jpg denied`

Comment: How are you trying to access those images? Are there any error messages?

Comment: By calling the url based on physical path , the only Error message is 403 forbidden

Comment: Please edit your question and add additional information. What is the full path of the two images, the URI you are using to access them, the access log and error log entries and the Nginx configuration file?

Answer (score 0):

Most servers will not work with permissions on 777 because too many permissions are very risky, most servers work perfectly with permissions in...

- Folders: 0755
- Files: 0644

We have a publication about how to configure the correct permissions: https://www.rolige.com/en/blog/how-to-assign-the-correct-permissions-to-my-prestashop-files-and-folders-n7

Comment: @Hamid Most of servers use that permissions, if this is not your case, you need contact with your hosting provider so you can check which ones are appropriate for your server.

Comment: I guess the problem is not for the  server permission , the prestashop cms uses .htaccess file for routing and rewrite some urls , it might be from that routing .htacess file!! but still I don't know how to fix that!

Comment: Try regenerating the friendly url by disabling this, save, enabling again, and save. Try also clearing all the cache from the performance tab and from your browser, or test in a private tab of your browser, you need to discard all types of cache.